# Correlation of the Möbius function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Assume that $$\sum_{n \leq x}\mu(n) \mu(n+1) \gg x.$$

Question. Does this contradict any well known results, say the prime number theorem or something like that?

Answer (score 27):

The relation you state contradicts the [recent result of Terence Tao](https://doi.org/10.1017/fmp.2016.6) that
$$ \sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\mu(n)\mu(n+1)}{n}=o(\log x).$$
Indeed, if $S(x)$ is the sum on your left hand side, we have
$$ \sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\mu(n)\mu(n+1)}{n}= \frac{S(x)}{x}+\int_1^x\frac{S(t)}{t^2}\,dt.$$

Comment: I may be missing something obvious, but could you point out *how* this contradicts the statement?

Comment: @sillyfly Since $S(t)>ct$ for some $c$ and large $t$, the integral on the RHS is asymptotically at least $\int ct/t^2=c\log t$.

Comment: @Wojowu: Yes. Let us also remark that $|S(t)|>ct$ for large $t$ implies that $S(t)$ cannot change sign for large $t$, hence also that $S(t)>ct$ for large $t$. In fact Tao's result can be (and should be) interpreted that $S(t)=o(t)$ holds in a certain average sense.